# How to find and store my device location to my sql db?

Tags: java, android, mysql, google-maps

I have used the code below to get my device location. Is there any better way to get the location with exact address or google map and i want to store the location in my database in `MySQL`.

```
public class Finder extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected String latitude,longitude; 
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you want to use the Google Maps API to do what you want.

Comment: sorry i have no idea about Google Maps API. My basic idea is to get exact location of the device but i was not happy with getting only longitude and latitude values as i have to store the location in my database also

Comment: What will you do after saving the location details in the database ?

Comment: You can use Google Maps API to send a location, and get back a variety of information (including "english" location information like address, etc.) Go to Google and check that informatoin out.

Comment: sorry Mr Sandeep i am not allowed to give those details

Answer (score 0):

You can check your current Address by using `Google Geocoder` class. You will get a list of near addresses, according to your latitude and longitude values. You can choose to receive only the first result, which is probably the one you want.

Check the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)